# CustomURLProtocol in browser: how to call windows explorer with unc path

Tags: windows, explorer, custom-url-protocol

I registered a [CustomURLProtocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx) `fileexplorer` in my registry. Its calling `cmd /c set url=\"%1\" & call set url=%%url:fileexplorer:=%% & call start explorer file:%%url%%`.

Calling local folders works well. `c:\mydata` opens in the fileexplorer with the URL `fileexplorer:c:%5Cmydata`.
**But how do I open an UNC-address like `\\myserver\mypath`?**
Running `call explorer file:\\myserver\mypath` from the cmd prompt works fine. A URL `fileexplorer:%5C%5Cmyserver%5Cmypath` fails (opening the explorer as if no path were given).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial & error I found this command:
`cmd /c set url="%1" & call set url=%%url:fileexplorerunc:=file:%% & call start explorer %%url%%`
The URL should be `fileexplorerunc://myserver/mypath` and it also works with local paths with `fileexplorerunc://c:/mypath`. This, of course, only works with windows OS.